# ngrok error failed to reconnect how can i fix this?

Tags: redirect, lookup, ngrok, failed-to-connect

Session Status                reconnecting (failed to dial ngrok server with address "connect.ngrok-agent.com:443": dial tcp: lookup
Version                       3.3.0
Latency                       -
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040

Connections                   ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90
0       0       0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00

Session Status                reconnecting (failed to dial ngrok server with address "connect.ngrok-agent.com:443": dial tcp: lookup
Version                       3.3.0
Latency                       -
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040

Connections                   ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90
0       0       0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00

how to fix this

Answer (score 2):

Running `ngrok diagnose` will give you more context

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I get the same issue sometimes. I found out that the wifi disconnects and the Ngrok server fails and tries to reconnect.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).